# How to build angular.dev site locally?

Tags: angular

The new angular.dev site has been launched and open sourced. I'd like to build it locally, but I can't run `yarn` smoothly in the Node 18 container. Here is what I tried.

Enter container:

```
docker run -it --rm -w /usr/src/app -p 4200:4200 node:18.18.2-buster bash
```

In the container:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular.git --depth=1
cd angular/adev
yarn
```

I get the following error message:

```
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @codemirror/tooltip@0.19.16: As of 0.20.0, this package has been merged into @codemirror/view
warning @codemirror/tooltip > @codemirror/state > @codemirror/text@0.19.6: As of 0.20.0, this package has been merged into @codemirror/state
warning @codemirror/tooltip > @codemirror/view > @codemirror/text@0.19.6: As of 0.20.0, this package has been merged into @codemirror/state
warning @codemirror/tooltip > @codemirror/view > @codemirror/rangeset@0.19.9: As of 0.20.0, this package has been merged into @codemirror/state
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-middleware > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-middleware > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
warning @angular/build-tooling > @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @bazel/typescript@5.8.1: No longer maintained, https://github.com/aspect-build/rules_ts is the recommended replacement
warning @angular/build-tooling > protractor@7.0.0: We have news to share - Protractor is deprecated and will reach end-of-life by Summer 2023. To learn more and find out about other options please refer to this post on the Angular blog. Thank you for using and contributing to Protractor. https://goo.gle/state-of-e2e-in-angular
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-dynamic-import instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-json-strings instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from@7.18.9: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-logical-assignment-operators instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-property-regex instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/preset-modules > @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-property-regex instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block instead.
warning @angular/build-tooling > protractor > webdriver-manager > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @angular/build-tooling > protractor > webdriver-manager > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning @angular/build-tooling > protractor > webdriver-manager > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning @angular/build-tooling > @microsoft/api-extractor > @rushstack/node-core-library > z-schema@5.0.6: has issues with node 14
warning @types/algoliasearch@4.0.0: This is a stub types definition. algoliasearch provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
warning firebase-tools > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning firebase-tools > superstatic > re2 > node-gyp > make-fetch-happen > cacache > @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
warning tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
warning @puppeteer/browsers@0.5.0: Invalid bin entry for "@puppeteer/browsers" (in "@puppeteer/browsers").
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @codemirror/autocomplete@6.10.2" has unmet peer dependency "@lezer/common@^1.0.0".
warning "@angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.0-rc.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/compiler-cli@^15.0.0 || ^15.2.0-next".
warning "@angular/build-tooling > @angular-devkit/build-angular > @ngtools/webpack@15.2.0-rc.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/compiler-cli@^15.0.0 || ^15.2.0-next".
warning "@angular/build-tooling > @angular/benchpress > @angular/core@14.3.0" has incorrect peer dependency "zone.js@~0.11.4 || ~0.12.0".
warning "@angular/build-tooling > @bazel/concatjs@5.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "karma-firefox-launcher@>=1.0.0".
warning "@angular/build-tooling > @bazel/concatjs@5.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "karma-junit-reporter@>=2.0.0".
warning "@angular/build-tooling > @bazel/concatjs@5.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "karma-requirejs@>=1.0.0".
warning "@angular/build-tooling > @bazel/concatjs@5.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "karma-sourcemap-loader@>=0.3.0".
warning "@angular/build-tooling > @bazel/terser@5.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "terser@>=4.0.0 <5.9.0".
warning " > postcss-scss@4.0.9" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.4.29".
warning " > tslint-eslint-rules@5.4.0" has incorrect peer dependency "tslint@^5.0.0".
warning " > tslint-eslint-rules@5.4.0" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.

$ yarn generate-all
yarn run v1.22.19
$ yarn generate-tutorials && yarn generate-docs && yarn generate-previews && yarn set-version && yarn generate-api && yarn generate-cli
$ ts-node scripts/tutorials/generate-tutorials.ts
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './generate-tutorials.ts'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/angular/adev/scripts/tutorials/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:125:19)
    at requireResolveNonCached (/usr/src/app/angular/adev/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:549:16)
    at getProjectSearchDir (/usr/src/app/angular/adev/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:519:40)
    at phase3 (/usr/src/app/angular/adev/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:267:27)
    at bootstrap (/usr/src/app/angular/adev/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:47:30)
    at main (/usr/src/app/angular/adev/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/angular/adev/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:579:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/src/app/angular/adev/scripts/tutorials/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.18.2
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Does anyone know how to build this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible since 17.2.

You can run the project locally with `yarn docs` or build it with `docs:build`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add more details on how to build `adev` site locally in the docker container.

1. Create a container for building the `adev` site

   ```bash
   docker run -it --rm -w /usr/src/app -p 4200:4200 node:18.18.2-buster bash
   ```
2. Fetch the Angular source code for `17.2.x` branch

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/angular/angular.git --depth=1 -b 17.2.x
   cd angular
   ```
3. Build `adev` site

   ```bash
   yarn
   yarn docs:build
   ```
4. The default output path will be under `dist/bin/adev/build/browser/` folder.